# Django Query Foreign Key and Many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Struggling with Django query, need some help.
So I would like to get data for 5 different variables, **accounts_data** = (only username), **user_account_data** = (name), **country_data** = (iso_code), **category_data** = (choice),  **permisisons_data** = (permissions).
All data of the models is connected with UserAccount table, so need to get data from other tables only for existing user_accounts

Example of models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class UserAccount(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category= models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    permissions = models.ForeignKey(Permissions)
    

class Country(models.Model):
    iso_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Category(models.Model):
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    connected_category = models.CharField(max_length=12)


class Permissions(models.Model):
    permission = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    restriction = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: Have you tried putting any relationships in yet?

Comment: yes, user_account_data = list(User_Account.objects.all()) and for foreign keys, for example for country_data -> country_data = Country.objects.filter(user_account__in=user_account_data).values('iso_code')

Comment: Okay... so once you've got a user account... you can get its related stuff via things like `user_account.country.iso_code` or `user_account.account.user.username` etc... Sorry - I'm not 100% sure what your question is... What query are you trying to do?

Comment: For example I would like to get all user_accounts, except id = 0000. So I'm using .exclude(id='0000'). And for all other user_accounts I would like to get connected data from other tables because this model have foreign key and manytomany relation

Comment: Yep... so exclude is the way to go there... then you loop over the accounts - then access the bits you want from those objects...

Comment: There is no need to filter every model to get required filed or fileds? I can access it from UserAccount model?

Comment: what do you mean by loop in this case?

Comment: Well... `for ua in UserAccount.objects.exclude(id='0000'): print(ua.account.name, ua.account.password)` etc...

Comment: Thanks Jon. Very helpful information!